# Codeigniter Controller name doesn't work with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a small Codeigniter application. I have one controller named "Vendor" which works perfectly, AJAX calls and all.
However, my second controller name "Ad" doesn't seem to work with jQuery AJAX. 
Everytime an AJAX call is made, the error handler is called.
Error output is:

```
statusText

"[Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/sbkch/backend/backend/assets/js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js :: b/a/a.open :: line 2"  data: no]"
```

However, as soon as I change the name of the controller to "Adthisisalongname", things start working as expected.
I tried playing around and renamed my controller to "Adverts". AJAX stopped working. Other methods are working fine (index, etc).
I then changed the name to Advendor and AJAX started working again.
What seems to be the problem? Are "Adverts" and "Ad" reserved keywords in Codeigniter?
I couldn't find any documentation pertaining to the same.
Please note that when the AJAX calls don't work, it doesn't even show up in Firebug as request being made to the server in the "Console" tab.
Also, I am not using `form_open()` function.

Comment: if request isn't being, the made problem is client side, not in server framework

Comment: Why does changing the name of the Controller fix it then?

Comment: the name of the class should match the name of the file name, ex. class myfoo extends CI_Controller { ..code here... }, then the controller  should be myfoo.php

Comment: Yup, I know. Still didn't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

client browser made this problem because they prevent adverbs to use ajax and hijacks user data, and it's not related to *Codeigniter* or *jQuery AJAX*

Comment: Can you cite some sources?

Comment: I realized on one of my project and I don't think you can find source. It's just reasonable reason for your problem!

Comment: Still need data to accept as answer, mate. :)
Will try this tomorrow at work (we are using ZF2 at work) and let you know.